# What is the way to detect if user installed my facebook application for the first time?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

Im looking for a way to check after user autorized to my facebook application, if he is a new user - just installed the app, or he was in the past and he did sign in... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way would be to add a table or log file to your application to record such events and check if this facebook user id exists in it already. Facebook used to have a post authorize callback url it would ping when the user first authorizes (or removed) your application but they have seemingly removed this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

partial solution,
you can use FB javascript api [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) 
this will return `connected, not_authorized` or `unknown` statuses

If the user is not currently connected to FB login status will be `unknown` which makes this solution not complete.

If the user IS currently logged into Facebook, then `connected` means he authorized your application and `not_authorized` means he didn't.

> couldn't really understand the documentation of the PHP FB api of equivilant [method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/), might be possible to do the same thing in php without javascript.